# Win 32 application is not launching in Win 64 bit OS

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, configuration, wix, wix3.8

In application there is no separate dependencies for 32 or 64 bit. It's a common WPF application and i'm not using any third party .dll.  If i pull the release folder files and run in it on Win 8.1 64 bit it's working. 
When i tried to run the application after the installation,`the application is not launching , no error message and even i tried to launch it from command prompt..no error message.`

I'm using Wix 3.8 to make the installer.

Here are the steps what i did so for:
VS 2012 Configuration manager:
Debug:
[image]

Release:
[image]

`PrintUtility is the exe of the applicaiton.`

`PrintUtilityExe is the BootStrapper of WIX.`

`SetupProjectInstaller is the .msi installer of WIX.`

When i made the installer through WIX: `SetupProjectInstaller.msi`and installed it on Win 64 bit 8.1, the application is not launching.

Here is the wix code: Product.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?define ProductVersion = "1.0.0.0"?>
<?define ProductUpgradeCode = "9fe100b5-8486-46c4-b3ab-15da1931ba4d"?>
<?define SourceDir = "C:\Users\krangaraj\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestPrintUtility\TestPrintUtility\bin\x86\Release" ?>
<?define SourceDirImages = "C:\Users\krangaraj\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestPrintUtility\TestPrintUtility\bin\x86\Release\Res" ?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="$(var.ProductUpgradeCode)"
           Name="TestPrint Utility" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="TTT" Language="1033" >
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" Comments="Windows Installer Package" InstallScope="perMachine"/>
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="TestPrintUtility.cab" EmbedCab="yes"/>
    <Icon Id="ProductIcon" SourceFile="TestPrintInstaller.ico"/>
    <Icon Id="TestPrintInstaller.ico" SourceFile="TestPrintInstaller.ico"/>
    <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="TestPrintInstaller.ico" />
    <Upgrade Id="$(var.ProductUpgradeCode)">
      <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)" OnlyDetect="yes" Property="NEWERVERSIONDETECTED"/>
      <UpgradeVersion Minimum="0.0.0" Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)" IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="no"
                      Property="OLDERVERSIONBEINGUPGRADED"/>
    </Upgrade>
    <Condition Message="A newer version of this software is already installed.">NOT NEWERVERSIONDETECTED</Condition>

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="TestPrint Utility">

          <Component Id="TestPrintUtility" Guid="{47D7C69E-81C2-4FD6-B77B-790FBF5F7B39}">
            <File Id="TestPrintUtility.exe" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\TestPrintUtility.exe" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
          </Component>
          <Component Id="bGround.png" Guid="{64AE1DAD-2502-4171-AF80-A153D59D8996}">
            <File Id="bGround.png" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\bGround.png" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cspstat.dll" Guid="{69CAD367-A9D1-46E7-B8BA-CF839D034175}">
            <File Id="cspstat.dll" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\cspstat.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
          </Component>
          <Component Id="TTT.I18N.dll" Guid="{B20D2708-0422-4617-815F-C9143A75833F}">
            <File Id="TTT.I18N.dll" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\TTT.I18N.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
          </Component>
          <Component Id="TTTDongleManage.dll" Guid="{B4A38CE6-C34E-4391-9DCA-A142DB3BCA66}">
            <File Id="TTTDongleManage.dll" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\TTTDongleManage.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
          </Component>
          <Component Id="HtmlAgilityPack.dll" Guid="{D63578BD-902A-4899-A0BF-C82146117B03}">
            <File Id="HtmlAgilityPack.dll" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\HtmlAgilityPack.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
          </Component>
          <Component Id="HtmlAgilityPack.pdb" Guid="{8CD7A15D-C92E-4F41-A097-8A06CFB01774}">
            <File Id="HtmlAgilityPack.pdb" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\HtmlAgilityPack.pdb" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
          </Component>
          <Component Id="HtmlAgilityPack.xml" Guid="{95B2ABCB-3E8C-4824-850C-7C3D29FB814D}">
            <File Id="HtmlAgilityPack.xml" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\HtmlAgilityPack.xml" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
          </Component>
          <Component Id="KGDLLV10.dll" Guid="{AB144098-3E3E-42AD-94A4-ED8F40E93915}">
            <File Id="KGDLLV10.dll" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\KGDLLV10.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
          </Component>
          <Component Id="Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll" Guid="{1EEF5A4C-B0AF-4528-8F57-80A8A62743EB}">
            <File Id="Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
          </Component>
          <Component Id="Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.xml" Guid="{8D772282-693B-4B4F-8D50-BC0A74F694E1}">
            <File Id="Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.xml" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.xml" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
          </Component>

            </Directory>


      </Directory>

      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuSubfolder" Name="TestPrint Utility">
          <Component Id="ApplicationShortcuts" Guid="12345678-1234-1234-1234-333333333333">
            <Shortcut Id="ApplicationShortcut1" Name="TestPrint Utility" Description="TestPrint Utility"
                      Target="[INSTALLDIR]TestPrintUtility.exe" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR"/>

            <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\TTT PIE\TestPrintUtility"
                      Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
            <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuSubfolder" On="uninstall"/>
          </Component>

        </Directory>
      </Directory>

      <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop">
        <Component Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" Guid="{C80E4373-F31A-4A2E-90A5-F3E2EFD149AA}">
          <Shortcut Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut"
             Name="TestPrint Utility"
             Description="TestPrint Utility"
             Target="[INSTALLDIR]TestPrintUtility.exe"
             WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR"/>
          <RemoveFolder Id="DesktopFolder" On="uninstall"/>
          <RegistryValue
            Root="HKCU"
            Key="Software/MyAppName"
            Name="installed"
            Type="integer"
            Value="1"
            KeyPath="yes"/>
        </Component>
      </Directory>


    </Directory>


    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallValidate"/>

    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    <Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="TestPrintUtility"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="bGround.png"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="cspstat.dll"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="TTT.I18N.dll"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="TTTDongleManage.dll"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="HtmlAgilityPack.dll"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="HtmlAgilityPack.pdb"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="HtmlAgilityPack.xml"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="KGDLLV10.dll"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.xml"/>



    </Feature>


  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Note: `To minimize it i removed some part of comportment code from the above lines`

Then i used this final piece code to make the final .msi:

```
set WIX_BIN=C:\Program Files\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\
echo Wix Toolset Bin Path: %WIX_BIN%
"%WIX_BIN%candle.exe" Product.wxs -ext WixUtilExtension
if exist Product.wixobj ("%WIX_BIN%light.exe" -out Product.msi Product.wixobj -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixUtilExtension)
```

Here is the `SetupProjectInstaller.wixproj` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>3.8</ProductVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>f5d8db53-64db-41d7-9cf9-fb9a151fd45b</ProjectGuid>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <OutputName>SetupProjectInstaller</OutputName>
    <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
    <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND '$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)' != '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
    <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>Debug</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Product.wxs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Utility\.Design\.Design.csproj">
      <Name>.Design</Name>
      <Project>{58a00d29-5dc5-4b9e-a18d-6fe6d1f0c1cf}</Project>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <DoNotHarvest>True</DoNotHarvest>
      <RefProjectOutputGroups>Binaries;Content;Satellites</RefProjectOutputGroups>
      <RefTargetDir>INSTALLFOLDER</RefTargetDir>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Utility\Utility.csproj">
      <Name>Utility</Name>
      <Project>{7316ff68-d2ba-4b9a-8d92-15e93ac7bc4e}</Project>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <DoNotHarvest>True</DoNotHarvest>
      <RefProjectOutputGroups>Binaries;Content;Satellites</RefProjectOutputGroups>
      <RefTargetDir>INSTALLFOLDER</RefTargetDir>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Utility\WPFSpark\WPFSpark.csproj">
      <Name>WPFSpark</Name>
      <Project>{98be1309-ceb4-45ee-b4ad-28baf0570fab}</Project>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <DoNotHarvest>True</DoNotHarvest>
      <RefProjectOutputGroups>Binaries;Content;Satellites</RefProjectOutputGroups>
      <RefTargetDir>INSTALLFOLDER</RefTargetDir>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />
  <!--
    To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it.
    Other similar extension points exist, see Wix.targets.
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    </Target>
    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    </Target>
    -->
</Project>
```

Please help me that how can i make it work on Win 64 bit OS. Thank you very much.

SS:
![enter image description here][3]

![enter image description here][4]
![enter image description here][5]

Edit:

Finally i moved my project to VS2012 on Windows 8 OS 64 bit. When i launch the project in VS & it's working fine.

In my understanding i'm making some mistake in Configuration side and also in WIX side. Any help guys???
`Note: The application can be installed on Win 32 without any problem.`

Comment: Have you checked the Event Log to make sure that there is no error message?

Comment: @Lukas Kubis: Application & .net run time Error. C:/WINDOWS\SYSTEm32\KERNELBASE.dll. .net frame work v4.0.30319

Comment: @NETscape: I have added the SS..it seems like there is a problem withKERNELBASE.dll & .net framework

Comment: I see `XamlParseException`. Try to surround `InitializeComponent()` in `MainWindow.ctor` using try-catch block, sometimes it helped me. Also check if all required libs are installed. Maybe you're using some library which wasn't installed and the initialization of MainWindow failed.

Comment: @Lukas Kubis: I'm checking all the details now. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: +1 for a well documented question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a 32-bit MSI (compiled as x86) and then try to install it on a 64-bit OS, the registry entries will get written to the WOW64 hive (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft).  The 64-bit version of Windows looks in the 64-bit registry hive and not the WOW64 registry hive when looking for custom registry entries.  In your WIX script I see that there are couple of registry entries which gets set, that might be going to the WOW64 hive and that could be the possible reason why your application is not running properly. One solution is to build the MSI in both x86 and x64, if it finally gets deployed to 32 and 64 bit OS.

Comment: Could you please explain this in details `One solution is to build the MSI in both x86 and x64, if it finally gets deployed to 32 and 64 bit OS.`

Comment: Attribute is invalid message: `"Platform="$(var.Platform)" `

Comment: Step 1: Before you implement the logic mentioned above, can you update your configuration manager to compile your setupprojectinstaller in x64 as opposed to x86 and then install your msi on the win64 machine to make sure everything is working fine?

Comment: So, i change it 64 in CM then make an installer? if so it'll generate only for x64 bit right? not for both 32 & 64.. I'm kind of lost with many things now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50048/discussion-between-linguini-and-isaiah4110)

Comment: Still i got no clue to fix this. The installer issue is really killing me :( please help me.